# C# console no longer appears

Tags: c#, console-application

Working on a multithreaded client/server application and the console just stopped showing up.

I threw in a `Console.ReadKey();` to see what would happen and this is the error I get:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.'`

Can anyone help? I would really like to have my console window back. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Was there no console window when you started the program?

Comment: Did you changed the `Output type:` _(Windows Application/Console Application/etc)_  on the projects property page?

Comment: Yes, that is the exception message that you get when you try to use ReadKey() in a console mode app that doesn't have a console window.  But you already knew that :)  One basic reason why it doesn't have one is because it got started with ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true.  So you are probably looking in the wrong place for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my application was that the `Output type:` on the projects property page had been changed from Console Application to Windows Application. Changing it back to Console Application brought back my console. Yay!